# Can I use the Linkedin api v1?

Tags: linkedin-api

I mean, This api works yet? I know that exist a version 2 but I really need to use the "People search API" but in the v2 I don't found it, are there any equivalence in the api v2?

Comment: I'm sure the documentation can answer this? Are you experiencing some specific problem?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes, I need to find a person by keyword but it functionality only appear in the "linkedin api v1" so I need to know if is possible to use the api v1 or Do I have to use the "linkedin api v2"?

Comment: Yes you are aight i am also facing same issue like few APIs i cannot found V2 so what should i do? have to use V1 deprecated api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API v1 can no longer be used as of May, 2019. Previously it was March 2019 but the deadline was extended.

> Editor's Note: We have updated this article to reflect the deadline
>   extension to the migration date. The new deadline is May 1. It was
>   previously listed as March 1. The extension is not applicable for the
>   JavaScript SDK.

More info here:

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates